# Python order of multiple elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

Does the order of multiple "elif" statements matter in python, specifically in string checking

for example:

```
if 'foo' in line:
  #do something
elif 'bar' in line:
  #do other thing
elif 'coffe' in line:
  #do other other thing
...
else:
  #something something
```

Comment: Yes it does. If one elif is True, the subsequent ones won't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the if-else statements are executing sequentially which means that python will run the if statement and if it is false then it will run the next elif and so on until the else statement that is executing only if all the above are false.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a switch statement which is a much more efficient way of checking through a lot of different scenarios like in your example. I have attached a link. https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html